# Autowire third party jar using annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm building a library which will be used by multiple clients. It's spring based library. I'm testing this library by adding as a dependency in another web application.

```
package com.mypackage;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:abc.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.abc.xyz")
public class AppConfig {

@Value("${myprod.password}")
private String password;

@Value("${{myprod.timeout}")
private String timeout;

@Bean
public BeanA beanA() {
    BeanA beanA = new BeanA();
    ....
    return beanA;
}

@Bean
public BeanB beanB() {
        BeanB beanB = new BeanB();
        beanB.setBeanB(beanA());
        return beanB;
    }
}
```

I have an `AppManager` in which I'm injecting `BeanB`

```
@Component
public class AppManager {

    @Autowired
    BeanB beanB;

    public void myMethod(){
      beanB.<some_method>();
      ....
    }
}
```

The above code is bundled as a jar and included in a web application as a dependency. Below is the code on Web application side which is acting as Client for this jar.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")
public class Client {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Client.class);
        AppManager appManager  = applicationContext.getBean(AppManager.class);

        appManager.myMethod(...);
    }
}
```

Couple of questions -

1. If I don't specify the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")` I get `No qualifying bean of type AppManager` error. How can I avoid `@ComponentScan` on the package? This is a shared jar with multiple clients, I don't want each client to be aware of the package which need to be scanned.
2. Can I just autowire the `AppManager` in `Client` rather than getting `ApplicationContext` and then bean?

I was hoping the client class to be like -

```
public class Client {
    @Autowired
    private AppManager appManager;

    public void aMethdod() {

        appManager.myMethod(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot auto wire static fields.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Corrected my question - I was testing it with a Main class but finally implementation would be a using non static member

Comment: I still see `static`. Nonetheless you still need something that creates the bean (the `ApplicationContext`) and they need to, at least know what the main configuration is they need to load (you can do that without an `@ComponentScan`). But either way they need to detect your config (which should create your `AppManager`) or scan everything.

Comment: if your beans are scanned by spring, they will be available in your app context, so you can autowire them where ever you want inside you app.

Comment: @M.Deinum - How can I load main Configuration without `@ComponentScan`? Any example? Also, I believe I will have to expose `AppManager` as bean by putting it in `AppConfig` so that I can access it.Correct?

Comment: By using either `@Import` to import the additional configuration, or by creating the `ApplicationContext` using that class as, instead of what you have now `Cliënt.class`.